# giving error while entering cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. command

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

I was going through https://shawnhymel.com/2096/how-to-set-up-raspberry-pi-pico-c-c-toolchain-on-windows-with-vs-code/ to setup toolchain in my PC but while going through I got error in final stage and error as follows:

```
$ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
CMake Error at pico_sdk_import.cmake:63 (message):
  Directory 'C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk' not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I already checked directory "C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk" and it exist at same location but when I commit to directory it does not go directly I have to access it one by one. that do not look like problem to me.

Is there anything else should I try to make this work?